# Simple Webserver for Windows for any Scripting Language

Tags: windows, embedded, webserver, embeddedwebserver

I am searching for a simple webserver that runs on windows and which runs code written in a scripting language. A requirement I have is that it supports HTTPS.

On Linux I could use a simple python script and load the OpenSSL module, but that does not work on Windows. Also I have found a Powershell server, but it has no HTTPS suppport.

So, maybe someone of you has a recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest IIS 5.x, 6.x, or 7.x which comes with Windows Server 2003 or 2008 all depending on what version of Windows you're running. It supports https, but it's hardly simple.  It has powerful capabilities, and can do classic ASP Server side scripting as well as a full blown .NET web apps. It all depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Manos http://jacksonh.tumblr.com/post/1159500924/manos-de-mono-the-manifesto is an option.